# How do I provision an hourly bare metal server from a flex image using the softlayer python API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I bumped into this article: https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/phil/Dedicated-server-ordering-Flex-Image-and-Python
But it's from 2012, the Softlayer API has progressed since then, and  it doesn't indicate how to provision onto an hourly server.

Is there a way to do this?  And is there a more up-to-date way of provisioning onto a monthly server (without using prices)

Thanks
Graham

Answer (score 0):

The basics have not change here you can see up dated articles about orders and prices:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/Location-based-Pricing-and-You
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-3

To order an hourly bare metal server you need to pick hourly prices, you can know that an price is charged hourly if it contains the "hourlyRecurringFee" property if the price does not contain that property it is charged mountly.

Another way to order hourly servers is using the:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject 
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/createObject method

you can see more information in these articles:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/ordering-bare-metal-servers-using-softlayer-api
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/phil/getting-started-ccis

If you take a look documentation about the https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject  method you will see that for set the image template you just need to configure the property:

```
"blockDeviceTemplateGroup": {
"globalIdentifier": "07beadaa-1e11-476e-a188-3f7795feb9fb"
}
```

This will create a CCI server, however if you want to create a bare metal server you need to use the https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/createObject method but with this method you are not able to set the image template, if you want to create a Bare metal server with flex image you need to use the placeOrder method (the approach using prices )